# Ubuntu upgrade path from 13.04 to 14.04

Tags: 13.04, 14.04, upgrade

I have an Ubuntu 13.04 laptop, which is 32-bit.

I know there is no possible way for direct upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. But how can I upgrade step by step, could you tell me how ?

Also in addition I tried many ways of upgrading, which includes downloading Ubuntu 14.04 .iso file form the Ubuntu website.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct upgrade from 13.04 to 14.04, but you can always upgrade to the last version by upgrade to all the intermediate versions.

This can be a long process, certainly if you were at a lower version than 13.04. But what you have to do, this to first upgrade to 13.10 and then upgrade to 14.04.

Note that if you have had a LTS version, like 10.04, 12.04 or 14.04 you can do the upgrade directly to the next LTS version (so upgrading directly from 12.04 to 14.04 would be possible, from 12.10 to 14.04 would not be possible directly).